# Can I get CSS property of the child and use it on the parent?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>

.child {
    background: red;
}
```

I have 5 parent divs with their child inside and each child has a different background color.

How I can get the child background color and reuse it as parent border color?

***Note:** Unfortunately, the childs background color is set and I cannot change it so I need some way to get it and reuse it for the parent.*

***Note:** I am aware that with CSS only this is not possible so If someone can help me with JS or jQuery.*

Comment: You can do it like this: https://codepen.io/Manoj6994/pen/wvJVaYE using [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: `$(".parent").each((i, e) => $(e).find(">.child").each((ii, ee) => $(e).addClass(ee.className)));`  https://jsfiddle.net/rmau49n8/

Comment: or the more common "go up" for css parent issues (ie select child then go up to parent rather than try to get children from parent) `$(".child").each((i,e) => $(e).closest(".parent").addClass(e.className));`  https://jsfiddle.net/rmau49n8/1/

Comment: @m4n0 In the Codepen I do not see the parent inherit the background of the child.

Comment: If you check the code. The background color is applied inline to the parent. Check the HTML.

Comment: @m4n0 no it is not and to see it just remove the child background colour and you will see that the background is gone.

Comment: See? https://nimb.ws/AX1TZc

Comment: @m4n0 Sorry, maybe refresh was needed and now I see the parent background color.
When I try to execute this script in the console I receive this "Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'."

Any idea?

Comment: Yes, because you need to access it using this code: https://nimb.ws/NwSIfB

Comment: @m4n0 everything is fine now, Thank you!